# How can square Cube collector.js be made to use a wss server?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

Anyone using Square [Cube](http://square.github.com/cube) for analytics? Wanting to see if anyone has successfully made its websockets work with https (i.e. as a wss server). Seems like the underlying websocket-server library has been abandoned in favor of socket.io, but wondered if anyone had incorporated it or found a proxy method for SSL connections.

Thanks.